# Java: How to convert a binary string to an image?

Tags: java, image, binary

I'm currently working on a tool to convert an image to a binary string and the other way around.

To convert the image to binary I use the following method:

```java
public void toText(String imagePath, String textPath) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", byteStream);

    byte[] bytes = byteStream.toByteArray();

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(textPath));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : bytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
    }

    writer.write(sb.toString());
    writer.close();
}
```

The output in the .txt file will then look like this:
`"10001001010100000100111001000111000011010000101000011010000..."`
I believe this code should work fine, please correct me if I'm wrong!

Now I want to convert the string back to an image. To do so, I wrote this code:

```java
public void toImage(String imagePath, String textPath) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(textPath)));
    String binary = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[binary.length() / 8];
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte((String) binary.subSequence(i * 8, i * 8 + 8), 2);
    }

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(imagePath));
}
```

The problem with this code is, that `"10001001"`, for example, is bigger than the maximum size of the `byte` (`137`). That's because `"10001001"` should in fact translate to the value `-119`, using the 2's complement representation.

How can I solve this problem? How do I know when to use the "normal" binary representation and when to use 2's complement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a flag which tells you that.

A `0` for numbers where you don't need the complement.

A `1` for numbers where you do.

Or in other words a flag which tells you if the number is positive or negative, which really is the way how a non-signed number is stored.